# Tensorflow sequence2sequence model padding

Tags: tensorflow

In the seq2seq models, paddings are applied to make all sequences in a bucket have the same lengths. And apart from this, it looks like no special handling is applied to the paddings:

the encoder encodes the paddings as well
the basic decoder w/o attention decodes using the last encoding which encodes the paddings
the decoder with attention attends to the hidden states of the padding inputs too
It would be really helpful if this could be clarified: is it true that, basically the paddings are just a special id/embedding, and the current seq2seq implementation treats them just like other embeddings? And no special mechanism is needed to ignore these padding, for example when encoding a sequence containing paddings; or to decode a sequence containing paddings using the attention-based decoder? So after padding, nothing special is done to the paddings, we can just pretend a padding is just another embedding (apart from maybe when doing the weighted x-entropy using target_weights)?

If the above is true, then when testing a trained model, is padding needed at all (since at test time, each sentence is decoded separately and not in a batch)? --- It looks like from the code, at test time an input sentence is still bucketed first and then padded?

Answer (score 1):

I think your basic premise is correct: the model does not treat the padding symbol differently than any other symbol. However, when packing the data tensors the padding always shows up at the end of decoder training examples after the 'EOS' symbol, and at the beginning of encoder training examples (because the encoder sequences get reversed.)

Presumably the model will learn that padding on the encoder side carries no real semantic information as it wouldn't correlate with anything of the other words...I suppose it could convey something about the length of the sequence when attention is factored in, but that wouldn't be a bad thing. The bucket approach is an attempt to limit the amount of excess padding.

On the decoder side the model will quickly learn that padding always occurs after the 'EOS' symbol so you ignore everything after the 'EOS' symbol is emitted anyway.

Padding is mainly useful because when running tensors in batches, the sequences all have to be the same size...so when testing one-at-a-time you really don't need to pad. However, when testing large validation sets it is still useful to run in batches...with padding.

(I have more questions and concerns about the *UNK* symbol myself.)

Comment: I arrived at this post because running a `seq2seq` model where the padding value (`-1` in my case) resulted in an error of the form `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,31] = -1 is not in [0, 53)` where `31` is the length of the first sequence in a batch and thus the index where the first invalid value occurs, and there are `53` positive integer symbols in the range `[0, 53)`  in my token vocabulary. I suppose this could be due to the fact that it expects the padding value to also be a part of the vocabulary, couldn't it?

Comment: yes the padding should just be a special token in your vocabulary and you'll let the seq2seq work out the value and embedding itself.